# How to travel through a Json file depending on user answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to develop a "game". You have different paths you can follow, like a storyline where you can decide the next step and I've created a Json like you can see below.

Now, the user receives a question and two options and the answer will influence the next question and answers. Like a tree structure.

I can't understand how I can travel to a Json childrens like this.
I have this so far:

```
{
  "label": null,
  "question": "Vamos começar a noite??",
  "children": [
    {
      "label": "Sim",
      "question": "Jantamos onde?",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "Casa",
          "question": "Qual?",
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Minha",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            },
            {
              "label": "Tua",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Restaurante",
          "question": "Qual?",
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Temudus",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            },
            {
              "label": "Pancinhas",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Não",
      "question": "Tens a certeza?",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "Sim",
          "question": "Vais para casa?",
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Em princípio sim",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            },
            {
              "label": "Talvez não",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Não",
          "question": "Vamos à praça?",
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Siga",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            },
            {
              "label": "Nem pensar",
              "question": null,
              "children": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "..." ,
        }).done(function ( data ) {
            console.log(data);

        //these are the first question and answers. And this works!!
        $('#titulo').html(data.question);
        $('#0').html(data.children[0].label);
        $('#1').html(data.children[1].label);

        //when the user clicks on one of the options
        $('.all_options').bind('click', function () {
            var op = event.target.id;
            console.log(op);

            if(op == '0'){

            }else{

            }

        });
    });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a head's up: you're not traversing JSON. You're traversing an object. JSON is a string format, and by the time you get to your `done` function, that's been parsed to an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store the current node in a variable?

```
//GLOBALS:
var data=null;
var node=null;
document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "..." ,
    }).done(function ( d) {
        node=data=d;
        showNewNode();
        init();
   });
});
function showNewNode(){
    //these are the first question and answers. And this works!!
    $('#titulo').html(node.question);
    $('#0').html(node.children[0].label);
    $('#1').html(node.children[1].label);
}
    //when the user clicks on one of the options
function init(){
    $('.all_options').bind('click', function () {
        var op = event.target.id;
        console.log(op);

        if(op == '0'){
           node=node.children[0];
        }else{
           node=node.children[1];
        }
       showNewNode();
    });
}
```

Comment: this worked just fine.. Just needed to save the current node as you explained.. Thank you :)